# Pyomo accessing solver status

Tags: pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, scip

I am solving a MINLP with Pyomo and Scip as an Solver.
After the problem is solved I automatically get this output:

```
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 13.00
Solving Nodes      : 1845
Primal Bound       : +5.21506487017157e+03 (26 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +5.21506487017157e+03
Gap                : 0.00 %
```

I want to save the values of this output. With the solving time it works like this:

```
results = opt.solve(instance)
Time = results.solver.time
```

However if I try the same with the Gap and the Nodes get an error:

```
AttributeError: Unknown attribute `gap' for object with type <class 'pyomo.opt.results.solver.SolverInformation'>
```

I have also tried using:

```
GAP = results.solution.gap
```

Which results in an output that says undefined.

Is there any other way to acess those two values.

Comment: I don't use `Scip`, but have you tried to run your model within `ipython` and then see what the auto-complete offers you after it has run?  You should end up in a live interpreter environment and you can inspect the objects (such as `results`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have tried it. Unfortunately `results` doesn't have the gap nor the nodes as a member.

Comment: That is a bummer.  If you really wanted to pick up those data points, you could capture the string output above and parse it to get those elements.  A little clunky, but it should only be a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks again. I will do it that way.